# How to create a composite primary with JPA (or Hibernate) annotations

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I got this problem which is a very common problem and I decided to share the resolution here.

The Problem:
I have a composite primary key in one of my tables. I need to map this with JPA annotations.

My POJO1:

```
public class Alarm {

    @Id
    @Column(name="alm_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="alm_description")
    private String desc;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "alm_norm_id")
    private Alarm normAlarm; 

    //getters and setters
}
```

My POJO2:

```
public class Equipment {

    @Id
    @Column(name="equ_id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name="equ_fixed_asset")
    private String fixedAsset;

    @Column(name="equ_service_tag")
    private String serviceTag;

    //getters and setters

}
```

So I have a table which the primary key is an `Equipment` + `Alarm` and I need to map that.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to create a separate class just for handle the primary key with `@IdClass` annotation. So I decided to use `@EmbeddedId` and `@Embeddable` annotations instead. The result was:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Alarm_Counter")
public class Counter {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CounterId id;

    @Column(name="aco_counter")
    private int counter = 1;

    @Column(name="aco_last_reset")
    private Date resetDate;

    public Counter(){}

    public Counter(CounterId id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    //Getters and Setters

    //...

    //Embeddable class for handling primary key
    @Embeddable
    public class CounterId implements Serializable{

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="aco_alarm_id")
        private Alarm alarm;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name="aco_equipment_id")
        private Equipment equipment;

        //Default Constructor
        public CounterId(){}

        //Constructor with fields
        public CounterId(Alarm alarm, Equipment equipment) {
            super();
            this.alarm = alarm;
            this.equipment = equipment;
        }

        //Getters and Setters
    }
}
```

I still needed to handle this object for persist it with hibernate. So I made the following:

```
Alarm al = alarmService.get(alarm);                 //Retrieve an Alarm object
Equipment eq = equipmentService.get(equipment);     //Retrieve an Equipment object

Counter ct = new Counter();                         //Instantiates a Counter object
CounterId cId = ct.new CounterId(alarm, equipment); //Instantiates a CounterId object (composite primary key for Counter)

ct.setId(cId);                                      //Sets the primary key (CounterId)
```

Comment: Well, you still ended up creating an inner class though. If you wanted, you could have created an inner class for `@IdClass` as well. But as an approach, the `@Embeddable` and `@EmbeddedId` is the more modern one.

Comment: Yeah, I've prefered to create an embeddable class instead of creating too much separated files.. Thanks ;)